# Footer logos aren't aligning correctly and overlap with footer content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having trouble getting the footer on my site to work. The footer is broken down into two sections. First section is the mainFooter area and the second is kind of the like copyright area.

I have logos in the copyright area and a logo in the mainFooter. I need to have two of them be aligned at all times. It's really one logo but split into both footers because it's a stupid logo.

This is it:

[image]

Because of that line, we have to split the footer in two sections. But the text "Art now" can never be misaligned with the building.

So my solution to this was to using absolute positioning on both elements, set right:0 bottom:0 and adjust their position using margin-top/bottom.

Problem is, this only works when the logo is really far out and not truly aligned with the rest of the content on the page since everything else is mostly centered. That's what I mean:

[image]

Personally I don't care too much about the alignment of the logo on the far right, at that point you've reached the end of the page, it doesn't overlap with the content in the footer and still looks pretty nice, but our clients designer (not web) is a stickler for these things.

[This is the dev site we're working on](http://aldagenais.pearcreative.ca/one-page)

**Does anyone have any ideas on how we could handle this? Have the logos in the footer but make sure things are aligned properly and aren't overlapping with the content in the footer?**

Comment: In the url provided it seems that all is aligned

Comment: Yea that one doesn't have the absolute position applied. So when you resize the browser Window, you'll notice that the text and building aren't always together and if you make your browser mobile size, the building moves completely to the left and overlaps other content.

Comment: You could make one only logo from logo and text and then align to the right making sure that it keeps aligned to the white line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a container div around the footer content (and logo's) that has the following css:

```
.container{
   width: 960px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
}
```

Now your absolute positioned elements will be positioned relative towards this container div, and will not move too far to the right, but stay in the bounding box instead.

Comment: @Batman Yes, obviously you'll need to adjust the position a bit more now until it's correct. But this should prevent the text from being misaligned.